# Ansible - playbook dynamic verbosity

Tags: docker, ansible, dockerfile

I want to build a docker image from a `Dockerfile`. I can do this by using the `bash` like this:

```
[root@srv01 ~]# docker build -t appname/tomcat:someTag /root/Documents/myDockerfiles/tomcat
```

The good thing about having the image build using the `bash` is, that it prints to `stdout` what it executes step-by-step:

```
Step 1 : FROM tomcat:8.0.32-jre8
8.0.32-jre8: Pulling from library/tomcat
fdd5d7827f33: Already exists
...
```

When using Ansible in the following fashion from bash:

`[root@localhost ansiblescripts]#  ansible-playbook -vvvvv build-docker-image.yml`:

Where the file `build-docker-image.yml` contains this content:

```
- name: "my build-docker-image.yml playbook"

  hosts: myHost

  tasks:

   - name: "simple ping"
     ping:

   - name: "build the docker image"
     become: yes
     become_method: root
     become_method: su
     command: /bin/docker build -t something/tomcat:ver1 /home/docker/tomcat
     #async: 1
     #poll: 0
```

It waits for the whole build command to finish and then prints all the `stdout` as **verbose output** together in one piece.

Commenting in `async:1` and `poll:0` doesn't solve my problem, since it doesn't print the `stdout` at all.

Comment: There was a [discussion](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3887) about streaming callbacks on GitHub a while back but was decided that it would be a huge amount of work and create a quite complicated architecture and as such was dropped.

Comment: This is not a docker related problem but an ansible response streaming issue